# Resizing a large image throws "Parameter not valid" when calling Image.FromStream()

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I'm trying to resize a large image that was uploaded by a user, and scale it down to thumbnail size.

I've [read that memory issues can cause problems with very large files](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/de298fd2-c5c9-4e2c-a6b0-778d43029885/systemdrawingbitmap-max-size?forum=netfxbcl?new_window), since it requires contiguous memory, but [my test image is only 5.78MB](http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap041225.html).

The code I'm using looks like this:

```
public static byte[] GetThumbnailImage(Stream imageStream, ImageFormat format, int thumbnailWidth)
{
    using (var thumbnailStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        imageStream.Position = 0;
        using (var image = Image.FromStream(imageStream))
        {
            var thumbnailSize = GetThumbnailSize(image, thumbnailWidth);
            using (var thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(
                    thumbnailSize.Width,
                    thumbnailSize.Height,
                    null,
                    IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                thumbnail.Save(thumbnailStream, format);
                return thumbnailStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's being called like this:

```
var thumbnailBytes = ImageHelper.GetThumbnailImage(imageStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg, 150);
```

Other smaller sized images do work without any error using this exact code. Is there any way I can alter this code to support larger images?

Update: Added using as suggested by @Hans-Passant, @Matias-Cicero and @Plutonix

Comment: Are you sure `imageStream` contains a valid image?

Comment: I just downloaded the image you linked and was able to call `Image.FromStream` just fine

Comment: You are being sloppy about calling Dispose().  Like you should **always** do for the thumbnail and image variables, be sure to use the *using* statement so it is clean and exception-safe.  Cutting corners on dispose/using is easy to do, that can work for a long time.  But not with the Image and Bitmap classes, they can require a lot of unmanaged memory and that makes them **very** unforgiving.

Comment: @HansPassant I can't see where I've missed a using statement. Can you give me a tip?

Comment: the `image` and the `thumbnail` vars are what he is talking about

Comment: @MatiasCicero That's interesting that you've managed to use that image without issue. I wonder if this is something inside ASP.NET. I assume you just used a test console app or test class?

Comment: No, it is bug in your code, disposing the image objects is not optional.  It just doesn't byte you in the face right away, it takes a while to consume all unmanaged memory.

Comment: Is my recent edit now what you meant by correctly using usings?

Comment: @Junto You should dispose `imageStream` outside your method call too (in case you aren't doing that already)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem in the past, and I think it was caused by the size of the image, which was equal to 0 ...

I solved using LoadImage method of this class.

You can adapt it to load the image before this call: *var thumbnailSize = GetThumbnailSize(image, thumbnailWidth);*

```
    public static class ImageLoader
    {
        // This isn’t going to help much – you’ll run out of memory anyway on very large images – but if you are keeping several in memory it might …
        public const int MaximumImageDimension = 10000;

        /// 
        /// Method to safely load an image from a file without leaving the file open, 
        /// also gets the size down to a manageable size in the case of HUGE images
        /// 
        /// An Image – don’t forget to dispose of it later
        public static Image LoadImage(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);

                if (!fi.Exists) throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.");
                if (fi.Length == 0) throw new FileNotFoundException("File zero lenght");

                // Image.FromFile is known to leave files open, so we use a stream instead to read it
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    if (!fs.CanRead) throw new FileLoadException("Can't read the file stream");

                    if (fs.Length == 0) throw new FileLoadException("File stream zero lenght");

                    using (Image original = Image.FromStream(fs))
                    {
                        // Make a copy of the file in memory, then release the one GDI+ gave us
                        // thus ensuring that all file handles are closed properly (which GDI+ doesn’t do for us in a timely fashion)
                        int width = original.Width;
                        int height = original.Height;
                        if (width == 0)
                            throw new DataException("Bad image dimension width=0");
                        if (height == 0) throw new DataException("Bad image dimension height=0");

                        // Now shrink it to Max size to control memory consumption
                        if (width > MaximumImageDimension)
                        {
                            height = height * MaximumImageDimension / width;
                            width = MaximumImageDimension;
                        }
                        if (height > MaximumImageDimension)
                        {
                            width = width * MaximumImageDimension / height;
                            height = MaximumImageDimension;
                        }

                        Bitmap copy = new Bitmap(width, height);
                        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(copy))
                        {
                            graphics.DrawImage(original, 0, 0, copy.Width, copy.Height);
                        }
                        return copy;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Data.Add("File", filePath);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```